Lower Bounds for the Operator norm of Integral Operators with square-integrable kernels
Let $k$ be a measurable function on $E\times E$ where $E \subset \mathbb{R}^2$, define the integral operator $L_k$ by
$$
L_k f(x) = \int_{E} k(x,y) f(y) dy, \qquad x \in E
$$
If $k$ is is square-integrable, then a standard fact is that
$$
\|L_k\| \le \|k \|,
$$
that is, the operator norm of $L_k$ is bounded above by the $L_2$ norm of $k$. I am wondering if there are also standard lower bounds for $\|L_k\|$ in terms of $k$?

If you meant whether there is a lower bound of $|L_k|$ in terms of $|k|_2$, then no. There is a sequence $k_n$ with $|k_n|2 = 1$ for all $n$ but $|L{k_n}| \to 0$.

(In fact, note that the space of all $L_k$ is exactly the space of Hilbert-Schmidt operators on $L^2(E)$, and the $2$-norm of $k$ is exactly the Hilbert-Schmidt norm of $L_k$. While the Hilbert-Schmidt norm is bounded below by the operator norm, they are not equivalent as long as $L^2(E)$ is infinite-dimensional.)

@DavidGao I see - are there any other standard techniques to derive lower bounds for $|L_k|$?

I’m not sure. But you might find the following helpful: Using the theory of Hilbert-Schmidt operators, one can show that any $k \in L^2(E \times E)$ can be written as $k(x, y) = \sum_n \lambda_n f_n(x)g_n(y)$ where ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$ are both orthonormal in $L^2(E)$ and the convergence happens in $L^2$. Then $|L_k| = \max {|\lambda_n|}$ (and $|k|_2^2 = \sum_n |\lambda_n|^2$). In particular, if $k(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$, then you actually do have $|L_k| = |k|2$. More generally, if $k(x, y) = \sum{n=1}^N f_n(x)g_n(y)$, then $|k|_2 \leq \sqrt{N}|L_k|$.

(Note: while in $k(x, y) = \sum_n \lambda_n f_n(x)g_n(y)$ I asked for ${f_n}$ and ${g_n}$ to both be orthonormal, this is not needed for the latter formulae $k(x, y) = f(x)g(y)$ and $k(x, y) = \sum_{n=1}^N f_n(x)g_n(y)$. The lower bounds I wrote in the second half of my answer hold without the assumption of orthonormality.)
